# How do I test in a var matches against a list of substrings in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I am fairly new to ansible and I am trying to determine how to test is a variable passed to my playbook matches against a list of substrings.

I have tried something like the following. Looping through my list of badcmds and then testing whether it is in the variable passed.

```
vars:
    badcmds:
     - clear
     - no

  tasks:


  - name: validate input
    debug:
       msg: " {{ item }}"
    when: item in my_command
    with_items: "{{ badcmds }}"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  "msg": "The conditional check 'item in my_command' failed. 
  The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on
 ({% if item in my_command %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}):  
 coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one problem with your playbook is that `- no` is automatically translated to boolean `false`. you should use "no" to make Ansible consider the variable as a string. without quotes:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    badcmds:
     - clear
     - no
    my_command: clear

  tasks:
  - name: print variable
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: 
      - "{{ badcmds }}"
```

output:

```
TASK [print variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "clear"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": false
}
```

I guess you should enclose `no` in quotes, because this behavior was not your intention.

to make a loop and check if the variable matches any item from the `badcmds` list, you can use:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    badcmds:
     - "clear"
     - "no"

  tasks:
  - name: validate input
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    when: item == my_command
    with_items: 
      - "{{ badcmds }}"
```

hope it helps